# The segment joining the midpoints of the $2$ bases of a trapezoid passes through the intersection of its $2$ diagonals

Tags: geometry

Prove that the segment line joining the midpoints of the $2$ bases of a trapezoid always passes through the intersection of the $2$ diagonals of the same trapezoid. [image: The picture]

I've tried to use Intercept theorem but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $\triangle AFC$ is similar to $ \triangle DFE$, next you can show that $\triangle AFG$ is similar to $ \triangle HFE$ and $ \angle AFG$ congruent to $\angle HFE$.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
Draw a line passing the mid-point E of CD and the intersection F of the diagonals.  EF produced meet the base AB at G. DC//AB gives 3 pairs of similar triangles, by which we have $$
\begin{aligned}
& \frac{x}{k}=\frac{A F}{FC}=\frac{FB}{F D}=\frac{y}{k} \Rightarrow x=y .
\end{aligned}
$$
Hence we have shown that G is the mid-point of AB.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Using the fact that ratio of the areas of two triangles with same height is equal to the ratio of their base, we obtained three pairs of triangles(same colors) with same areas and hence the area of $\Delta ANF$ is equal to that of $\Delta BNF$.
$$
\because \frac{\Delta A N F}{X}=\frac{NF}{FH} =\frac{\Delta B N F}{Y} \Rightarrow X=Y, 
$$
$$\therefore x:y=X:Y=1:1$$
and then $H$ is the mid-point of $AB$.